# Where is the official manifest / definition of google colab's environment?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Is there a website or git repository where there is a clear listing of all the python packages and other dependencies installed on Google CoLaboratory? Is there a docker image that corresponds to a Google CoLab environment?

Comment: Overall, these first 4 answers, some more helpful than others, don't answer the question. The reason I want a website is for programmatic access to not only the pip-installed packages, but the version of Python itself, and other pertinent environment attributes. https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2800

Answer (score 1):

I see your question is to view the already installed packages in google colab.

You can run this command for viewing it:

```
!pip list -v | grep [Kk]eras
```

You can also view all the packages, through this command:

```
!pip list -v
```

For more info, visit [this link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/aviadr1/learn-advanced-python/blob/master/content/10_package_management/10-package_management.ipynb#scrollTo=HecBSOomHiF1).

Answer (score 0):

As of Sep 13, 2022, the Colab team started providing the [pip-freeze and apt lists](https://github.com/googlecolab/backend-info) for what is included the Google Colab runtimes.

Found this when trying to replicate the Colab environment locally during some troubleshooting steps.

Answer (score -1):

You can find out about all the packages installed in Colab using

```
!pip list -v
```

Where it shows you the packages' names, versions, locations, and the installer.

Comment: Thanks @Mohana, I am looking for a location where the list is posted, like a Dockerfile, a github repository which is used as the source manifest, something like this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html, etc.

Answer (score -1):

There is no clear listing of all the packages and dependencies installed on Google CoLaboratory. However, you can use the !pip freeze command to list all the packages that are currently installed in your environment.

The github repo for the Google CoLaboratory environment is here: [link](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools) and you should be able to see the imported package dependencies in this file [link](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/190c19930ce6fc38859874a9b359ba769e726403/setup.py)

Comment: Thanks, but the link you provided is not exhaustive. For example, matplotlib and seaborn are not listed.

Comment: Also, the docker link seems to be to a Tensorflow docker image.

Comment: And see previous question for why the repo has not be helpful.